# Is using a volume absorption shader on the world incompatible with transparent background renders?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, volumetrics

I'm using Cycles in Blender 3.1.2. I'm trying to get the light volume effect over transparency for compositing later using a 2D program. The goal is to get the window and the light beams coming through it over transparency.

But it keeps rendering with a black background. Is using a volume absorption shader on the world incompatible with transparent background renders?

I'm using a world volume shader with the surface set to transparent. I've also tried with the surface node unplugged. I've also tried using png and EXR formats. The "Transparent" option under "Film" in Render Settings is checked.

I've looked at other questions, but they were outdated or not the same issue that I'm having.

Why is the background still rendering as black when the Transparent option is enabled and the world surface is transparent?

Do I need to set this up another way, such as using a finite volume shader constrained in a cube rather than a world volume?

[image]

Comment: The issue with world volume is often that the volume is so big as to make it practically fully dense everywhere.  You might have more luck with a large volume object.